# udpclient.receive() suddenly stops receiving

Tags: c#, udpclient

I'm using `UdpClient` to receive data from a single host(actually it's a microcontroller that sends 32 bytes of data every 4 milliseconds.
The program I wrote is pretty simple.
I'm initializing the `UdpClient` like this(in Program.cs):

```
public static UdpClient client = new UdpClient(1414);
```

after that i do this in Form_Load event:

```
static UdpClient client = Program.client; 
IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
```

and then call the `client.Recieve()` like this:

```
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {                       
                        try
                        {
                            data = client.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);                            
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            String err_type = ex.GetType().Name;
                            if (err_type == "SocketException")
                            {                                    
                                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Find The Device.", "Device Error.");
                            }
                        }                                                        
                    }
                });
```

the program runs fine on my own system (using Windows 10). However when i run this program on windows 7,at random times,but with 100% chance `client.Recieve()` stops working and the program no longer receives any data. no exception is thrown. to find the root of the problem, I installed Wireshark to test if there is any incoming data.The answer was no(the LAN port light stops blinking too) .  What has me confused is that this does not happen on windows 10.

Comment: Could be a firewall issue

Comment: There's no particular reason to assume your program is at fault, as opposed to the device or the network stack. For example, the machine could be sending a packet the device does not expect, causing it to stop processing. Make sure that any firewalling is disabled, capture all traffic on the interface (not just that port or only UDP), and compare the W7 and W10 traces.

Comment: Are you sure the `client` isn't disposed? _(using(var client = .....))_

Comment: @J.vanLangen where should i use this statement? in the declaration or the assignment?

Comment: @JeroenMostert i have verified that firewall is disabled and my executable is allowed to go through firewall,also the laptop with windows 7 has no antivirus installed. Doesn't Wireshark capture every received packet?

Comment: It is probably throwing a exception, but you are doing Task.Run(), winch is fire and forget, use Task.Run().Wait(), and the exception should be propagated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code was completely fine.
This was a hardware problem on our side.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you miss all exceptions except SocketException. 
To find out, what's going on, please, rewrite your catch block:

```
Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {                       
                        try
                        {
                            data = client.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);                            
                        }
                        catch (SocketException ex)
                        {

                                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Find The Device.", "Device Error.");

                        }  
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                                MessageBox.Show(e.GetType().Name, e.Message);
                        }

                    }
                });
```